# Can not run updates on Bionic 18.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, software-center, policykit

So I had a problem with Xenial and thought it would be solved when I upgrade to Bionic but I still have the issue. After doing a fresh install of Bionic, I tried to update everything using the 'software updater' and this is the error it gave me:

```
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.44'}): org.debian.apt.update-cache
```

Previously I couldn't run Ubuntu software center without opening it in terminal first and even then I had to use gksudo software-center to be able to download anything. When I click on software center and try to install something it gives me that error. When I click on Synaptic, nothing happens, doesn't open. But when I run sudo synaptic everything seems to be okay, installs and searching, etc. I just prefer Ubuntu software center because of the pictures and descriptions, I know which is the correct file to install and on Synaptic, it looks like I'm just adding a random file and I have to wait until it installs to see if its the right one, stupid reasoning, I know. So I guess the only issue I'm currently having is just being able to click programs for them to work and being able to run update manager. I'm not sure what else to put in this message as far as commands or outputs but if you request I input something specific, I can do that and paste the output here to show you.

[edit, output from command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LKDI.png)

Comment: `ps -ef | grep polk` please edit your question for output.

Comment: do u know what that output means? i edited my original question and put a link to what u requested but that was the only way i know how to attach it was take a screenshot and upload the pic

Answer (score 0):

There is no policykit agent running.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall policykit-1-gnome
```

Make a reboot.

I could swear the agent would startup with your desktop-session, after reboot.

sorry for link [add application on startup](http://ttps://askubuntu.com/questions/37957/how-do-i-manage-applications-on-startup-in-gnome-3/645919#645919)

I don't use gnome3 for about 2 years.

Comment: i ran that line into the terminal and everything went though okay, rebooted, ran the other line of code, ps -ef | grep polk and got the same output, tried to update again just to make sure and its still acting the same way.

Comment: https://imgur.com/zfvkAUf